# Domain and maximum value of a function

Tags: calculus

Find u,v such that $∫(6−x−x^2)dx$ (from u to v) has its largest value.

I simply calculated the integral in u,v and then used the first derivative test, which showed me 4 critical points. Then I used the second derivative test and found 3 saddle points and a maximum at (u,v) = (-3,2). 
(These are simple calculations, so I omitted them)

The model solutions pretty much agree with that, but with one difference: They start normally by defining g(u,v) to be equal to the integral, but then

'' The boundary of the domain of g is the line u = v; on that line g = 0. '', and my question is: why does it have to be u =< v, since integrals are very well defined even if u > v?

Answer (score 1):

There is an implied assumption that $u \le v$, because if we allow the lower limit of integration to exceed the upper, then you can make the integral attain arbitrarily large values; e.g., evaluate $$\int_{x=10}^{-10} 6 - x - x^2 \, dx = \int_{x=-10}^{10} x^2 + x - 6 \, dx.$$

That said, there is a much easier method of solution that does not rely on integration, if what is desired is simply the values of $u$ and $v$.  The solution relies on the fact that the integrand describes a parabola, which when factored, gives $$6 - x - x^2 = -(x-2)(x+3).$$  Therefore, the integrand is nonnegative if and only if $x \in [-3, 2]$, from which it follows that $u = -3$, $v = 2$ yields the maximal value of the integral, since if $-3 < u$ or $v < 2$, the resulting area is strictly smaller; whereas if $u < -3$ or $v > 2$, again the area is smaller because you've begun to include an interval for which the integrand is negative.

Comment: I think I see what you mean for the domain. As for the second part, it is indeed a nice and simple solution, but under exam conditions, I suspect that sticking to the universal method for finding extrema is more time efficient... thanks!